Dispositions with repetition itertools
I am learning to use the Itertools in Rust but can't figure out how to get the dispositions with repetition (I guess we just use different names for the API?).

Order matters
Elements can be taken from the set any number of times
Resulting tuple is of length k

The domain from which symbols are taken is a set (elements are unique) but can be taken any number of times.
For example to generate all possible binary sequences with k bits (domain is [0, 1]) with k = 3 expected result is
[0 0 0]
[0 0 1]
[0 1 0]
[0 1 1]
[1 0 0]
[1 0 1]
[1 1 0]
[1 1 1]

Related permutations with repetition in Rust

https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.permutations -> If you are looking for permutations with replacements, use repeat_n(iter, k).multi_cartesian_product() instead.

Thanks @Dogbert I will post an example for future readers because the doc for this case doesn't provide an example
use itertools::{Itertools, repeat_n};
const SYMBOLS: [u8; 2] = [0, 1];
pub fn main() {
    let k = 3;
    let res: Vec<Vec<u8>> = repeat_n(SYMBOLS.iter().cloned(), k).multi_cartesian_product().collect();
    res.iter().for_each(|line| {
        println!("{:?}", line);
    })
}

